# O que signifca "grau" na expressão "concordo em gênero, número e grau"?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, concordância-verbal

Quando uma pessoa concorda completamente com algo que outra acabou de dizer é comum ouvir, pelo menos no Brasil:

> Concordo contigo em gênero, número e grau!

Entendo a idéia da expressão acima, de concordar incondicionalmente em todos aspectos com a idéia anteriormente exposta. A expressão faz referência, creio eu, à existência da concordância nominal no Português, onde p.ex. um adjetivo concorda com o substantivo ao qual se refere em gênero (masculino ou feminino) e número (singular ou plural).

**TL;DR**

Nesta expressão, o que significa concordar em *grau*?

Comment: o grau do adjetivo.   http://www.normaculta.com.br/grau-do-adjetivo/

Comment: também o grau dos substantivos (aumentativo e diminutivo)

Comment: @Centaurus Mas, ao contrário do gênero e número, não existe concordância (flexão de um substantivo, p.ex.) com o grau, não é?

Comment: Não entendi a tua pergunta.  Poderias reformulá-la?

Comment: @Centaurus, eu achei que a expressão citada "Concordo em gênero, numero e grau" vinha do fato de concordar com o que alguém disse, ao mesmo tempo em que faz referência à concordância nominal da Gramática Portuguesa. Mas na gramática não existe concordância com o grau de um substantivo. Neste sentido perguntei "Por que concordar com o grau"?. Em outras palavras, eu acho que a expressão deveria ser apenas "Concordo em gênero e número", omitindo o grau! Ficou mais claro?

Comment: existe o grau dos adjetivos.  Por exemplo:  "lindíssima" = feminino, singular, superlativo.  Concordo que ela é lindíssima.  Concordo em gênero, número e grau.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a exemplo do que tu citaste sobre gênero e número, explicando com exemplo seria grau que é dividido em 3 tipos seria isso:

> - Comparativo de igualdade: Lucas é tão extrovertido quanto seu irmão.
> - Comparativo de inferioridade: Lucas é menos extrovertido (do) que seu irmão.
> - Comparativo de superioridade: Lucas é mais extrovertido (do) que seu irmão.

assim a concordância em grau. ok?